# Is there an R function to identify and modify column names across dataframes in the same List?

Tags: r, stringr, readxl

I am downloading an excel workbook with data across multiple years, separated by year into different sheets. Each sheet has approximately 70 columns and col_names.

Unfortunately some columns have slightly different names for the same data.

```
sheets <- excel_sheets(filename)
SheetList <- lapply(excel_sheets(filename), read_excel, path=filename)
names(SheetList)<- sheets
```

which loads a list of 13 elements (dataframes) separated by year. If I look at 2019 colnames I get

```
colnames(SheetList[[1]])

[1] "Number"                                               
 [2] "Year-Round Vacancy"                       
 [3] "Premier Beds"                
 [4] "Total Year Round Beds"
.
```

and so on, versus 2013 colnames

```
colnamesnames(SheetList[[6]]) 

[1] "Number"                                               
 [2] "Year-Round Vacancy"                       
 [3] "Premier Rooms"                
 [4] "Total Year Round Rooms"
```

...and so on

In these two cases, these columns are the same data labeled differently.

I understand I could use a str_replace_all for column names three and four but was curious if there is a more elegant way for identifying discrepancies and renaming columns (where applicable)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the columns are arranged in the same order and represent the same data, then you can create a vector and assign that quickly to the dataframes:

```
column_names <- c('Number', 'Vacancy', 'Premier', 'Total')

names(Sheet1) <- column_names
names(Sheet2) <- column_names 
...
```

I understand for 70+ columns that would be a bit of an inconvenient vector, so not sure this helps.

You might also just assign the names from one dataframe to another:

```
names(Sheet1) <- names(Sheet2)
```

This would sync them up.